# Can you create a new record in sequelize using data found in another table(record) in one step?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables; one that contains information for racers (users basically, but it's for a racing game), and another that stores detailed results about a race.

Racers have (among other things) a characterId, vehicleId, teamId, and their primary key id.

When a race is finished, a RacerResult record is made with and populated with the 4 fields above, plus additional information: namely, what race was it on and what place did you get?

For example: when race 1 ends with 4 players, 4 new RacerResults are created, all with the same raceId but the rest depends on the racer (racer 1 might have been using character 3 on team 2, etc).

The associations are defined as: RacerResult.belongsTo(Racer) and Racer.hasMany(RacerResult).

I'm wondering: is there a way to get the characterId, vehicleId, and teamId given a racerId within the RacerResult.create method (using include or findOne: { where: ... } ?

Or do I have to do something like:

```
racerinfo = Racer.findByPK(id, {attributes: ... })
RacerResult.create(
  characterId = racerinfo.characterId,
  ...
)
```

Comment: If you already have a link field in `RacerResult` to `Racer` there is no need to copy `characterId` to `RacerResult` you can always get it from `Racer`. Or you have to store a xharacterId that was in `Racer` at the moment of a creation of `RacerResult` record?

Comment: Correct; the characterId changes for Racers an arbitrary amount of times. So I always need to check before the RacerResult record is created ‘what character were they just using?’